# dpkg and egrep on Ubuntu 18

Tags: ubuntu, grep, dpkg

Trying to use `dpkg` and `egrep` commands to list packages whose names starts with `q`. Already tried:

```
dpkg -l | egrep -l q
dpkg -l | egrep -l ^q
dpkg -l | egrep q
dpkg -l | grep q
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: What is the result and how is it different from what you expect?

Answer (score 4):

Use `--get-selections` instead of `-l` option:

```
dpkg --get-selections |grep ^q
```

Or using `awk` to change the column order:

```
dpkg -l |awk '{print $2 , $3 "\t\t" $1}' | grep ^q
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't really need grep (or egrep) at all here: the `dpkg -l` command accepts a pattern:

```
-l, --list package-name-pattern...
    List packages matching given pattern.
```

Note that `package-name-pattern` is a glob pattern not a regular expression. So

```
dpkg -l 'q*'
```

If you want the output in more configurable format (for example, only the binay package name) then you can use `dpkg-query` instead ex.

```
dpkg-query -Wf '${binary:Package}\n' 'q*'
```

Answer (score 1):

The regular expressions for egrep do not match the expected output of `dpkg -l`. If you wish to keep the same output format as `dpkg -l`, which includes the sate of the package, the version and a description, then the regular expression needs to be changed to match the expected format: three characters at the start of the line (describing the state of the package on the system) and a space before the package name.

In the expression `^... [qQ]`, `^` indicates to match from the start of a line, `...` says to match any three characters followed by a space, then `q` matches packages that start with either an upper or lower case "q" (packages should only be lowercase on Ubuntu but there may be custom packages that do not follow these rules).

```bsh
$ dpkg -l | egrep '^... [qQ]'
ii  qdbus                                         4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1                        amd64        Qt 4 D-Bus tool
ii  qemu-block-extra:amd64                        1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.19                      amd64        extra block backend modules for qemu-system and qemu-utils
...
```